# Player 2 in Tony Hawk's Proving Grounds keeps eating pavement in spite of attempts at grinding

Tags: tony-hawks-proving-grounds

Challenging a mate on the Nintendo Wii version of *Tony Hawk's Proving Grounds* it seems as though neither of us can work Player 2 to a level where they can grind when sliding onto railings, curbs or lips. The best they can is to skate up, flick the controller and smash their teeth into the obstacle.

Player 1, however, has no trouble and not only can grind, but pull off the whole swag and gamut of tricks and flips. They're pretty much unlocked, and fully tapped which gives them an easier time to navigate a course.

Head-to-heads such as Graffiti and HORSE are painfully one-sided. Even resorting to cheat codes like LOTSOFTRICKS does nothing for a level playing field.

How do you unlock it so that Player 2 has a fighting chance to pull off simple tricks beyond ollies?

Comment: This is on the premise/assumption that unlocking Player 1 will give all players in goof off time the same level of tricks

Comment: Have you checked to make sure all the wii controller's buttons work for player 2?  Try switching the motes.

Comment: Tried switching them, but Player 2 is still eating dirt and planting face @pil

Comment: Are you sure you cant load a profile using the player two controller?

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem may be that the character used has stats/tricks that are not equivalent to player one. Simply have the character progress through the story to unlock the moves and you should be set.

If I remember correctly, all customized skaters can only use the tricks they learned, to not overwhelm the players with too many options.